# Fujitsu S1300i advances document but doesn't scan

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, sane, fujitsu-siemens

I'm using a Fujitsu ScanSnap S1300i.

Using `sudo` as a temporary workaround to minimise any permissions problems:

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5 [FUJITSU], product=0x128d [ScanSnap S1300i]) at libusb:001:004
```

So I edited `/etc/sane.d/epjitsu.conf` and added:

```
firmware /usr/share/sane/epjitsu/1300i_0D12.nal
usb 0x04c5 0x128d
```

and copied `1300i_0D12.nal` from a Windows install into `/usr/share/sane/epjitsu/`. (Actually I copied all the `*.nal` drivers, just in case it needed one of the others.)

```
$ sudo scanimage -L
device `epjitsu:libusb:001:004' is a FUJITSU ScanSnap S1300i scanner

$ sudo scanimage
scanimage: output is not a file, exiting
```

And running `sudo simple-scan`, `skanlite` or `gscan2pdf` all advance the document feed by a couple of centimeters, but then the feed halts and the fronted returns an I/O error of some kind.

So SANE seems to recognize the scanner and has some basic communication with it (the paper advances a couple of centimeters), but it doesn't scan.

Any suggestions about something I've missed out or how to get a proper scan output?

**Additional info**

```
$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.23; backend version 1.0.23
$ sudo skanlite
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave
```

If I run `sudo scanimage -v` (I accidentally typed lowercase V when I was trying to obtain the version!) after the document has been advanced a couple of centimeters by `sudo skanlite`, then the `scanimage` command forces a complete document feed -- but no scan.

Comment: I've pretty much seen the same thing and that included building my own sane from source. The last I'd seen about this printer on the sane mailing list when I looked earlier in the year is that its completely unsupported by sane and its operation is different enough to the other models that it would have to be reverse engineered from scratch.

Comment: I've had a similar issue.  This is the thread I started with no resolution.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/567863/s1300i-scanner-issues-under-ubuntu-14-10-using-sane  Possibly helpful to you.  If you do figure it out, do let me know.

Comment: This guy https://www.josharcher.uk/code/install-scansnap-s1300-drivers-linux/ seems to have solved it...though this probably will not help the OP after 3-4 years